# Fullcalendar strange display issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

I have noticed that in Fullcalendar, if I use "jquery ui" theme, the first row in agenda week has a lighter background (`#F8F8F8` vs `#EEEEEE`).
[image: here is an example]

Here is my script:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js'></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var calendar;
    $(function() {
      calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        themeSystem: 'jquery-ui',
        eventTextColor: '#000000',
        themeButtonIcons: false,
        header: {
          left: 'month agendaWeek agendaDay',
          center: 'prev title next',
          right: 'today'
        },
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        minTime: '07:00:00',
        maxTime: '19:00:00',
        slotEventOverlap: true,
        editable: false,
        eventLimit: true
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='calendar'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Obviously I'd like to have the same color all around.
Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you create a **working** snippet so we could debug it? It's much easier to help you tis way.. Also, why don't just override its css?

Comment: I edited my question with a full code example...

Comment: I edited your question so it's actually working.. Can you supply the missing `jquery-ui.theme.css` so we could see the problem?

Comment: I inserted the cupertino theme, but it's the same with other themes (I didn't try them all of course...) and here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mvarnier/o0mqgst9/

Comment: You can override the style with `.fc-week td` selector. like: https://jsfiddle.net/e1y30n84/2/

Comment: this changes the background of the "all day" row, but the first row (7 a.m.) is still lighter

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you correctly, now I think I do, please, read my answer.

Comment: if you don't like the colour supplied by the theme, just change it. At the jQueryUI website you can even make your own completely custom theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you diving deeper in the css you can see this style:

```css
.ui-widget-content {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  /* the lighter background comes from the this rule */
  background: #f2f5f7 url(images/ui-bg_highlight-hard_100_f2f5f7_1x100.png) 50% top repeat-x;

  color: #362b36;
}
```

[image]

(Open the full size image)

So, just set it to whatever you want, like this:

```css
.fc-time-grid .ui-widget-content {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js'></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var calendar;
    $(function() {
      calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        themeSystem: 'jquery-ui',
        eventTextColor: '#000000',
        themeButtonIcons: false,
        header: {
          left: 'month agendaWeek agendaDay',
          center: 'prev title next',
          right: 'today'
        },
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        minTime: '07:00:00',
        maxTime: '19:00:00',
        slotEventOverlap: true,
        editable: false,
        eventLimit: true
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='calendar'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It works. thanks. I actually dived deep in the css but I didn't find the solution... thanks again!

Comment: Sure :) My pleasure

Answer (score 0):

Make the cell background-color !important

.fc-unthemed .fc-content, .fc-unthemed .fc-divider, .fc-unthemed .fc-list-heading td, .fc-unthemed .fc-list-view, .fc-unthemed .fc-popover, .fc-unthemed .fc-row, .fc-unthemed tbody, .fc-unthemed td, .fc-unthemed th, .fc-unthemed thead {
    background-color: #F8F8F8!important;
}